# JavaScript TO Bean in SEAM + JSF 1.2

Tags: javascript, jsf, javabeans, seam2

I want to save the variable "position" in my BEAN, does anyone know how to do this? I'm starting in javascipt.

```
 function placeMarker(position, map) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
      });
      map.panTo(position);
      alert(position);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to include an `<h:inputHidden>` component on the page on the page and assign its value through the use of Javascript.  When you bind the hidden input to a managed bean property then the next time this inputs form is submitted to the server it will apply its request value to the managed bean property.

```
<h:form id="googleMapForm">
  <h:inputHidden id="positionInput" value="#{managedBean.positionProperty}" />
  <h:commandButton id="myButton" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

In javascript if you know the ID of the positionInput on the page then you can get it in jQuery.

```
var positionVar = jQuery('#googleMapForm\\:positionInput');
if (positionVar) {
  positionVar.val(position);
}
```

If you execute this script before submitting the form then the value of position should be applied to the managed bean property.